# I am trying to create a set of rows by adding an ArrayList to each row, data being fetched from an API, but it gives an error

Tags: android

I am trying to make a set of five rows by adding an ArrayList to each row, the number of rows are five, but I still get an error of Index Out of Bounds.

This is my logcat :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: in.silive.mytvapplication, PID: 9980
                                                                         java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
                                                                             at in.silive.mytvapplication.Fragments.MainFragment.loadRows(MainFragment.java:201)
                                                                             at in.silive.mytvapplication.Fragments.MainFragment.access$100(MainFragment.java:51)
                                                                             at in.silive.mytvapplication.Fragments.MainFragment$1.OnTaskComplete(MainFragment.java:118)
                                                                             at in.silive.mytvapplication.Network.FetchData.onPostExecute(FetchData.java:92)
                                                                             at in.silive.mytvapplication.Network.FetchData.onPostExecute(FetchData.java:27)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Here is how I am trying to add rows :

```
public class MainFragment extends BrowseFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<HashMap<String, List<Movie>>>, OnTaskComplete {
    private static final String TAG = "TAG";


    private static final int NUM_ROWS = 1;
    private static final int NUM_COLS = 20;
    private static final int BACKGROUND_UPDATE_DELAY = 300;
    private static ArrayObjectAdapter mRowsAdapter;
    private static int i = 0;
    private final String[] api_url = {"film/recent_films/", "film/trending_films/", "film/toprated/", "film/most_liked/", "film/most_viewed/"};
    Context context;
    ProgressDialog sprogressDialog;
    private Drawable mDefaultBackground;
    private Timer mBackgroundTimer;
    private DisplayMetrics mMetrics;
    private URI mBackgroundURI;
    private BackgroundManager mBackgroundManager;
    private HeaderItem header;
    private boolean dataLoaded = false;
    private static String user_search = "";
    Bundle sbundle;

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        /*if (outState == null) {
            FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_browse_fragment, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }*/
        //super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

    }

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate-MainFragment");
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity();
        prepareBackgroundManager();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate-MainFragment_background prepared");
        sbundle = getArguments();
        if(sbundle!=null){
            user_search = sbundle.getString("SEARCHQUERY");
            Log.d("TAG","user search : "+user_search);
        }

        setupUIElements();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate-MainFragment_ui elements placed");
        mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ListRowPresenter());
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                sprogressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                sprogressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
                sprogressDialog.show();
            }
            final int finalJ = j;
            new FetchData(j, context, api_url[j], new OnTaskComplete() {
                @Override
                public void OnTaskComplete() {
                    **loadRows(i);**
                    if (finalJ == 4 && sprogressDialog.isShowing())
                        sprogressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).execute();
        }
        dataLoaded = true;



        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate-MainFragment_row adapter implemented");
        setupEventListeners();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate-MainFragment_event listeners applied");

    }


private void loadRows(int n) {

        //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"value of i"+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //new FetchData(getContext(),"film/recent_films/").execute();
        List<Movie> list = ListMovies.getMovies(context);

        if (n != 0) {

            Collections.shuffle(list);

        }
        //mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ListRowPresenter());
        CardPresenter cardPresenter = new CardPresenter();

        ArrayObjectAdapter listRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(cardPresenter);
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
            try {
                listRowAdapter.add(list.get(j));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem(n, ListMovies.MOVIE_CATEGORY[n]);
        mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, listRowAdapter));



        /*for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                Collections.shuffle(list);
            }
        }*/

        //HeaderItem gridHeader = new HeaderItem(i, "PREFERENCES");

        GridItemPresenter mGridPresenter = new GridItemPresenter();
        ArrayObjectAdapter gridRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(mGridPresenter);
        //gridRowAdapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.grid_view));
        //gridRowAdapter.add(getString(R.string.error_fragment));
        //gridRowAdapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.personal_settings));
        //mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(gridHeader, gridRowAdapter));
        if (i == 4) {
            setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);
        }

        i++;
    }
```

The ListMovies class :

```
public final class ListMovies {
    public static final String MOVIE_CATEGORY[] = {
            "Recent Films",
            "Trending Films",
            "Top Rated",
            "Most Liked",
            "Most Viewed",
    };
    public static Context c;
    public static VideoData v = new VideoData();
    public static ArrayList<String> mtitle = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mdesc = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mvideourl = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mcardurl = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mcategry = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mstudio = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<Integer> mviews = new ArrayList<>();
    public static String bgImageUrl = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/android-tv/Sample%20videos/April%20Fool's%202013/Introducing%20Google%20Nose/bg.jpg";
    public static List<Movie> slist;
    int index;

    public ListMovies(int i, ArrayList<String> st, ArrayList<String> sd, ArrayList<String> sv, ArrayList<String> sc, ArrayList<String> mcat, ArrayList<String> mstu,ArrayList<Integer>mvw) {
        //this.c = ct;
        this.index = i;
        this.mtitle = st;
        this.mdesc = sd;
        this.mvideourl = sv;
        this.mcardurl = sc;
        this.mcategry = mcat;
        this.mstudio = mstu;
        this.mviews = mvw;
        setMovies(index);
        //getMovies();
    }

    public static List<Movie> getMovies(Context cc) {
        c = cc;
        /*new FetchData(c, " ", new OnTaskComplete() {
            @Override
            public void OnTaskComplete() {
            }
        }).execute();*/
        slist = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        Log.d("TAG","size obtained : "+mtitle.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < mtitle.size(); i++) {

            slist.add(buildMovieInfo(mcategry.get(i), mtitle.get(i),
                    mdesc.get(i), mstudio.get(i), mvideourl.get(i), mcardurl.get(i), bgImageUrl,mviews.get(i)));
        }


        return slist;
    }

    private static Movie buildMovieInfo(String category, String title,
                                        String description, String studio, String videoUrl, String cardImageUrl,
                                        String bgImageUrl,Integer no_of_views) {
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setId(Movie.getCount());
        Movie.incCount();
        String stitie, sdesc;
        try {
            stitie = new String(title.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
            sdesc = new String(description.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
            movie.setTitle(stitie);
            movie.setDescription(sdesc);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        movie.setStudio(studio);
        movie.setCategory(category);
        movie.setCardImageUrl(cardImageUrl);
        movie.setBackgroundImageUrl(bgImageUrl);
        movie.setVideoUrl(videoUrl);
        movie.setViews(no_of_views);
        return movie;
    }

    public void setMovies(int pos) {

        /*v.titles[pos] = mtitle;
        v.description[pos] = mdesc;
        v.cardUrl[pos] = mcardurl;
        v.videoUrl[pos] = mvideourl;
        v.category[pos] = mcategry;
        v.studio[pos] = mstudio;*/


    }
}
```

loadRows(int n) is the function I am using to add rows.
Line number 201 is : `HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem(n, ListMovies.MOVIE_CATEGORY[n]);`

Comment: It says exception with index value 5 and the array has 5 elements, so, from 0 to 4. How do you call it? May be you need to sustract 1. Where is the logic when you make the call?

Comment: The function loadRows(i) is being called inside the loop under OnActivityCreated. The loop variable j is set to 0 and runs till j<5.. which is 5 times only.

Comment: Are you talking about the line **loadRows(i);** . There it says i not j

Comment: It is called with an argument 'i' for a different purpose, but it will be called 5 times from the loop, which has the loop variable as 'j'.

Comment: I think should post the complete code for that call. The error is clear. Maybe there is something on that logic which you think it is ok but ii is not.

Comment: I have added the complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of variable 'i' is not well defined. So it would be good to the variable 'finalJ' instead of 'i'.

Just give a try as loadRows(finalJ):